# Can a multilingual Sitecore 6 web page have an alias for each language?

Tags: sitecore, vanity-url

Can a multilingual Sitecore 6 content pagehave an alias for each language? It appears that I can only add one per content page.

For instance, labour_market_survey.html has an english page and a french page:

http://www.site.ca/en/labour_market_survey

http://www.site.ca/fr/labour_market_survey

But I can only give the content page one alias:
http://www.site.ca/survey

How can I add a french alias, such as:
http://www.site.ca/enquete ?

[image: language options] 
[image: one alias per page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are just sort of web-root-level "links" to certain items, mostly intended to use for marketing campaigns as short and friendly Tokens. To achieve what you want you may consider few options:

1. If you have configured an individual website for each language - then you may  create `SiteAliasResolver` processor for `HttpBeginRequest` pipeline. This will give you an option to have aliases on website level. Please reed [this blogpost](http://www.suneco.nl/over-suneco/blog/2014/building-aliases-on-website-level-in-sitecore.aspx) describing how to achieve that (with code samples).
2. Another option would be to use **Redirect Module**, as it will do exactly what you need. There was a [question on Redirect Module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33104681/5125707) recently, so there is exact example how to create a redirect item for any virtual URL that will do 301 to any specific sitecore item (which belong to some page item under corresponding language website):
   [image]
3. If you are resolving languages on-a-fly so that the same item in Sitecore serves different languages (based on criteria how you resolve that), then you may use aliases as they are (but as I understood from your example that isn't your case)

P.S. Also, if you decide to go with aliases, mind Canonical URLs ([link one](http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/07/impact-of-sitecore-aliases-on-seo.html) and [link two](http://mikael.com/2013/01/seo-canonical-urls-in-sitecore/)) as they may affect your SEO.

Comment: Martin, the same item in Sitecore serves different languages (see included photos above). I will try the Redirect Module.

Comment: The version of Sitecore 6 we have is a "not-for-profit" version that lacks the Redirect Module. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please take redirect module from here https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule there is both installation package and sources, documentation and the rest